# asyncpg - connection vs connection pool

Tags: python

I am going over [`asyncpg`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html)'s documentation, and I am having trouble understanding why use a connection pool instead of a single connection.

In the [example given](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/examples.html), a pool is used:

```
async with pool.acquire() as connection:
    async with connection.transaction():
        result = await connection.fetchval('select 2 ^ $1', power)
        return web.Response(
            text="2 ^ {} is {}".format(power, result))
```

but it could also be done by creating a connection when necessary:

```
connection = await asyncpg.connect(user='postgres')
async with connection.transaction():
    result = await connection.fetchval('select 2 ^ $1', power)
    return web.Response(
            text="2 ^ {} is {}".format(power, result))
```

What's the advantage of using pools over connections as necessary?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Establishing a connection to a database server is an expensive operation.  Connection pools are a common technique allowing to avoid paying that cost.  A pool keeps the connections open and leases them out when necessary.

It's easy to see the benefits of a pool by doing a simple benchmark:

```
async def bench_asyncpg_con():
    power = 2
    start = time.monotonic()
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        con = await asyncpg.connect(user='postgres', host='127.0.0.1')
        await con.fetchval('select 2 ^ $1', power)
        await con.close()

    end = time.monotonic()
    print(end - start)
```

The above completes on my machine in 1.568 seconds.

Whereas the pool version:

```
async def bench_asyncpg_pool():
    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(user='postgres', host='127.0.0.1')
    power = 2
    start = time.monotonic()
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        async with pool.acquire() as con:
            await con.fetchval('select 2 ^ $1', power)

    await pool.close()
    end = time.monotonic()
    print(end - start)
```

Runs in 0.234 seconds, or *6.7 times faster*.

Comment: Do you advice to use client side connection pooling even when using something like pgPool?

Comment: I got 6.5s and 0.75s (running in a VM), but also interesting to note: 0.6s for 1000 `pool.acquire()`, and 0.15s for 1000 `con.fetchval()`. So the `acquire()` appears to be 4x more expensive than the `fetchval()`, or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Moreover, connection pools handle reconnection, while with a single connection you have to handle reconnection yourself.

Comment: @davidtgq you could try increasing `min_size` and `max_size`. `acquire()` would lock, until a connection to run a query against is available. So if all the connections have been taken, it waits until at least one of them is free. Which makes waiting take up more time than the actual work itself. You have to tinker with the parameters to suit your workload better.

Answer (score 4):

*Elvis Pranskevichus* showed two benchmarks above. I took the first one `bench_asyncpg_con` and edited it, moving the `con` outside the loop:

```
async def bench_asyncpg_con_2():
    power = 2
    start = time.monotonic()
    con = await asyncpg.connect(**data)
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        await con.fetchval('select 2 ^ $1', power)

    await con.close()
    end = time.monotonic()
    print(end - start)
```

And this worked much faster than `bench_asyncpg_pool`

I got `0.45` on this, whereas I got

`1.62` on `bench_asyncpg_pool` and

`63.18` on `bench_asyncpg_con`

I'm kinda newbie in using this lib and thinking that one connection `con` for a whole project would be a good choice. Correct me if I'm wrong. I will appreciate it

Comment: If you are only ever running one query at a time in your application a single connection is fine. However, most applications which use a database also handle multiple things at the same time (e.g. multiple requests for different clients through a webserver). In those cases a single connection quickly becomes a bottleneck, but creating a new connection for each request is expensive too. That's why connection pools are used. Your test program runs a purely sequential process, if your real program works that way too a single connection is fine.