# Use SQL inside of a Discord Cog

Tags: python, sql, discord, discord.py, pgadmin

I did not want to fall back to you all but I am lost.. I have a discord python bot and I'm using SQL to store data though out the bot. The main file I got the SQL working to make it only connect once instead of multiple connections. In the COG how would I do that?

What I have tried:

```
def __init__(self, bot):
self.bot = bot
self.db = asyncpg.create_pool(dsn='postgres://postgres:Password1@localhost:5434/discord')

        
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
print("Level Online!")

@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx):
    guild = ctx.author.guild
    member = ctx.author
    self.db.execute('INSERT INTO levels(member, guild_id) VALUES ($1, $2)', member.id, guild.id)
```

This is in a class by the way! I am open to any ideas, please and thank you.

Comment: look at the part 2 of the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242093/asyncpg-connection-vs-connection-pool and this might help as well https://gist.github.com/jegfish/cfc7b22e72426f5ced6f87caa6920fd6. I think you are not using `db.acquire` so you are being limited by one connection

Comment: @Equinox I tried that, Im using a cog where his is the main file. I can get the connection started but cant access it through out the code.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @Equinox i ended up using .connect instead of pool and I no longer have errors thanks for the help!